# Size of global variable is different from size of return list

Tags: java, list

I have a variable `public static List<Integer> allBooksIDs`, which is defined globally and initialized in a constructor as `allBooksIDs = dbFunctions.getAllBookIDs();`

The issue is that when I check the size of the list `allBooks`, the value is 28, however when I check the size of the list returned by `dbFunctions.getAllBookIDs()` method - its 57. Is there anything I am doing wrong way?

getAllBookIDs()

```
public List<Integer> getAllBookIDs(){
    List<Book> allBooks = getAllBooks();
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Book b : allBooks){
        res.add(b.getId());

    }
    return res;
}   

    private List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    Query query = manager.createQuery("from books");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**UPDATE**

So, the issue resolved, but I didn't understand, why the variable was updating. I had a mathod that was assigning the values of the global variable to another variable `List<Integer> nonRatedBooks = allBooksIDs`, and after that the variable was updating. I just chaged to:

```
List<Integer> nonRatedPubs = new ArrayList<>();
nonRatedPubs.addAll(allBooksIDs);
```

Can anyone explain, why it was so? So that I don't make the same failure in future.

Comment: How are you checking the size?  I don't see how this is possible based on the actual code you showed us above.

Comment: "I have a variable `public static List<Integer> allBooks`". That's a bad idea. That being said, you need to provide more info on how the lists are populated.

Comment: `allBooks` don't seems to be defined globally in your code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I guess he's using a getAllBookIDS().size() :D Are you sure the query returned by `manager.createQuery("from books")` return a list of size 57?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen at first, I just used `allBooks.size()` and `res.size()`, and then also iterated over the elements and printed the values to the console

Comment: When you print the values in the console, do you get 57 or 28 different values?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti when I print the values that are retrieved using getAllBookIDs() I get 57 values, that I actually have in DB. Then after `allBooksIDs = dbFunctions.getAllBookIDs();`, when I check `allBooksIDs`, there are only 28 values that actually correct, meaning I have them in the DB

Comment: You sure you're not removing objects from the DB after the first call and before the second one?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I am sure. I just call the method once in order to get the DB values to the global variable and use them further. There is no any changing in this variable at all.

Comment: Try debugging: does allBooks has size 57 or 28 in the second call of getAllBookIDs?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti check updated post.

Comment: Because you were assigning a reference to the `b` variable, and by changing it, you weren't actually changing `b` but the memory at which `b` (and also `a` - the first variable) was pointing at.

Answer (score 4):

You have a variable inside `getAllBookIDs()` that is named `allBooks`, so the `List` that this method returns will be the internally defined `allBooks`, not the globally defined `allBooks` object.

Comment: Masking of variable names seems plausible +1

Comment: the name of static variable is different. My fail. Have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of masking and initializing the variable `allBooks`. The first step is that you are initializing `allBooks` in the constructor with

```
constructor{
  allBooks = dbFunctions.getAllBookIDs(); // returns a list
}
```

At that point it's the correct size, but later on if you add more `Book`'s you are no longer updating the static `allBooks` field and that's because of masking the variable name inside the `getAllBookIDs` method.

```
public List<Integer> getAllBookIDs(){
    List<Book> allBooks = getAllBooks(); // this is a local field with the exact name as the static field and thus it will not assign it to the static field.
}
```

Comment: the name of static variable is different. My fail. Have edited the post.

Comment: @Cap Then my first statement is probably the one you are looking for. Everytime you call `getAllBookIDs` it will return a new `ArrayList` and thus will not be reflected on the static field unless you assign it to it.

Comment: the issue is, I just assign values once to this variable. Other methods are just using it.

Comment: @Cap Yes, as I said your constructor init is the current snapshot of `dbFunctions.getAllBookIDs()` it will not update itself with the new Objects when you add more Books.

Comment: I understand that. I am not adding any values there. I just need to read them, without performing any other operation =)